# Aiohttp and Asyncio give an error when writing a bot on aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp, aiogram

I'm writing a bot on Aiogram. I did everything according to the documentation, but I get an error. I'm seeing her for the first time. Please help me solve the problem

```
def on_startup(bot: Bot) -> None:
    asyncio.create_task(start_schedule(bot))


async def start_schedule(botself):
    aioschedule.every().day.at('00:00').do(lottery.lottery_finish, botself)
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode='html')
    dp = Dispatcher()

    dp.startup.register(on_startup)

    dp.include_routers(main_menu.router, order.router, report.router, phone.router, location.router, receipt_scan.router, admin_panel.router, lottery_panel.router, products_panel.router, post_panel.router, markets_panel.router, early_close_panel.router, code.router, pre_admin_panel.router, availability_panel.router)
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

error in text format:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\PycharmProjects\chester_users2\bot.py", line 44, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\PycharmProjects\chester_users2\bot.py", line 39, in main
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 526, in start_polling
    await self.emit_startup(bot=bots[-1], **workflow_data)
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 230, in emit_startup
    await self.startup.trigger(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\event.py", line 42, in trigger
    await handler.call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 48, in call
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, wrapped)
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\PycharmProjects\chester_users2\bot.py", line 18, in on_startup
    asyncio.create_task(start_schedule(bot))
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 360, in create_task
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
ERROR:asyncio:Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x00000224FFE334C0>
ERROR:asyncio:Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x00000224FFE133A0>, 6128.968)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x00000224FFE33340>
ERROR:asyncio:Fatal error on SSL transport
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x00000224FFE33970>
transport: <_ProactorSocketTransport fd=596 read=<_OverlappedFuture cancelled>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 684, in _process_write_backlog
    self._transport.write(chunk)
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 359, in write
    self._loop_writing(data=bytes(data))
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 395, in _loop_writing
    self._write_fut = self._loop._proactor.send(self._sock, data)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'start_schedule' was never awaited
Exception ignored in: <function _SSLProtocolTransport.__del__ at 0x00000224EFC60D30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 321, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 316, in close
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 593, in _start_shutdown
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 598, in _write_appdata
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 706, in _process_write_backlog
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 720, in _fatal_error
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 151, in _force_close
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

StackOverflow asks for more characters because there is a lot of code in the question. don't pay attention to this text

Comment: Please post the error as a text, not an image.

Comment: See if this helps you https://pythonalgos.com/2022/01/09/runtimeerror-event-loop-is-closed-asyncio-fix/

Comment: You can try [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html) library instead of asyncio. I guess it's better for telegram bots.

Answer (score 0):

```
  File "C:\Users\DTEAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 48, in call
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, wrapped)
```

This looks like your problem. The library is running the startup code in a thread, so if you try to get the running loop, it fails.

This seems like bad practice for an asyncio library to be spawning a thread for this kind of use case. I'd suggest opening an issue and seeing what the library maintainers think, but if they want a startup task to be run asynchronously I'd expect them to accept an async function and run it with `asyncio.create_task()` as you did here.

In the meantime, maybe you can figure out a way to get the loop from the main thread and use `loop.call_soon_threadsafe()` as a workaround.